# Redis - Mongo integration for managing duplicate information

Tags: node.js, mongodb, session, node-redis

I have a Node application that I have recently changed from single core with a cookie session to multi core ( using cluster ) and a Redis store to handle the sessions.  Mongo is my data store and one of the most used objects I have is what I call a 'User' object.  Here is the model for it ( mongoose ):

```
// define the schema for our user model
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({ 
    username : String,
    access : Number,
    blocked : Number, 
    login : {
        lastLogin : Date,
        amt : Number 
    },
    appData : {
        fontSize : String,
        pageState : {}
    }
});
```

Now the appData.pageState portion of this object gets modified constantly as the user browses around and basically as the user goes from section to section in my app that object turns into something like this:

```
appData: 
{ 
    pageState: 
    { 
        foo: 5,
        bar: 41,
        baz: 23
    }, 
    fontSize: '16px' 
}
```

The numbers represent the last page visited of it's respective section.  The whole point to this is so when the user jumps from section to section, the last page they visited is the one they are served when they return. If they log out of the app and come back I want this to be stored, so they can leave where they left off.

I have a session : `req.session.user` that upon login is the same as the user model.

```
req.session.regenerate(function(){
    // Store the user object from the database into the session
    req.session.user = user;
    res.redirect('/home');
});
```

When I navigate from section to section and page to page, I am saving the pageState into Mongo and then updating the session data.

```
User.findOne({'_id' : req.session.user._id },function(err, user){
    if( err ){ }
    else if( user ){
        //page state
        if( user.appData.pageState === undefined ){
            user.appData.pageState = {}; // initialize with an empty object
        }
        user.appData.pageState[path] = id;
        user.markModified( 'appData.pageState' ); // let Mongo know we have modified our nested schema

        user.save(function( err ) {
            if( err ){  }
            else{ 
                req.session.user.appData = user.appData; //copies the Mongo data object to the redis session store
                req.session.save();// saves the new session data
            }
        });
}
```

});

When I jump into a new section I get the session data for that page

```
app.get('/:section', function(req, res){
    var section = req.params.section;
    res.render(section, { appData : req.session.user.appData })
});
```

So here's the question: Is there a way I can take advantage of the speed of the redis store and have redis update mongo when it changes automatically?